# Get regular x-label values on Grafana > Status History

Tags: visualization, grafana

I have an image that is showing count of occurrences by version over time.
[image]

The problem is my x-axis is a disaster.  Those are dates, but spaced....randomly?  Looking around in the settings I'm not seeing the usual "X Label > Spacing" possibility.  So how do I get this human-readable?

Comment: I guess Grafana is really confused by your data. Status history is supposed to be used for statuses within same windows for all series. Based on your screenshot, I doubt your data is in this format. Looks more like a use case for state timeline.

Comment: @markalex: thank you!  didn't know about "state timeline", it's much cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Grafana is really confused by your data.

[Official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/status-history/) on Status history panel says:

> Status histories show periodic states over time.

Status history is supposed to be used for statuses within same windows for all series. Something like this.
[image]

Based on your screenshot, I doubt your data is in this format.

It looks more like a use case for [state timeline](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/state-timeline/): it doesn't align timestamps of the states, and thus doesn't attempt to process dates shown on time axis into some kind of uniformity.